# Where do music files except .mp3 go?

Tags: 8.0, music

I am using Lumia 720 and all the music files except .mp3 are lost in the phone. I am not able to find it. Please help.

Comment: You seem to have combined two questions in to one. Consider posting as separate questions.

Comment: About the music files, how did you get them on to the phone?

Comment: And what other music formats do you have? mp4, m4a, ogg?

Comment: What do you mean by "lost in the phone"?

Comment: Do you mean that when you plug your phone into your computer and browse it with Windows Explorer, the only files that you can see are MP3s?

Comment: What I mean is I can play only .mp3 files. If I add .avi or anything else they are not present in the phone. Neither in the music player nor in the windows explorer.

Answer (score 1):

The built in music app will happily play [most common music file formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), like mp3 or wma. In your comments, you refer to avi, which is a video format, rather than a music format, and as long as that is using a supported codec, it should be playable in the videos app